Google Translate is not working in popupWin.document.write
I am trying to call google translate inside window.open but it's not working. When adding the Google translate script it showing blank page. I have shared with you the script code.
<script type="text/javascript">
    function print() {
        var tableHtml = `<table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Items</th>
                                <th class='number-left'>Qty</th>
                            </tr>`;
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            tableHtml += `<tr>
                            <td>${item.name}</td>
                            <td class='number-left'>${item.qty}</td>
                        </tr>`;
        });
        tableHtml += `</table>`;
        tableHtml += `<script>
                        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                            new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');}
                            </sc'+'ript>
                            <script src='https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'></sc'+'ript>
                     `;
        tableHtml += `<br><div id="google_translate_element"></div>`;
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=400,height=400');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head>'+
                                '<style>' +
                                '.number-right{text-align: right;}' +
                                '</style>'+
                                '</head><body onload="window.print()">' + tableHtml + 
                                '</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }
</script>

I need to display Google Translate in popupWin.document.write. How I can achieve that?

document.write is deprecated and causes problems. Consider using createElement in your scenario.

I have used it but it's not working.
